# Using AudioTrack in AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC?

Tags: android, audio, audiotrack

I've found lots of tutorials and posts showing how to use `AudioTrack` to play wav files in `AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM` and I've successfully implemented [this example](http://www.martinhoeller.net/2012/01/13/developing-a-musical-instrument-app-for-android/).

However I'm having issues with performance when playing multiple audio tracks at once and thinking that I should first create the tracks using `AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC` then just call play each time.

I can't find any resources on how to implement this.  How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried just constructing your `AudioTrack` instance, calling `write` once with your entire sample array, and then `play` ?

Answer (score 3):

The two main sticking points for me were realizing that .write() comes first and that the instantiated player must have the size of the entire clip as the *buffer_size_in_bytes*.
Assuming you have recorded a PCM file using AudioRecord, you can play it back with STATIC_MODE like so...

```
File file = new File(FILENAME);
int audioLength = (int)file.length();
byte filedata[] = new byte[audioLength];
try{
    InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(FILENAME));
    int lengthOfAudioClip = inputStream.read(filedata, 0, audioLength);
    player = new AudioTrack(STREAM_TYPE, SAMPLE_RATE, CHANNEL_OUT_CONFIG, AUDIO_FORMAT,audioLength, AUDIO_MODE);
    player.write(filedata, OFFSET, lengthOfAudioClip);
    player.setPlaybackRate(playbackRate);
    player.play();
 }
```

Comment: How do you get the resource using bundled android resources?
Is there something like this available?
byte[] fileData = getRawResourceById( R.raw.FILENAME );

Comment: Do you mean ringtones and built-in sounds? I'm not sure if you could hardcode the resource IDs just because every phone is different. To access all the media files programmatically you would use:  android.os.Environment.

Comment: I found it. Thanks
`inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.hello_world);`

Comment: @Pescolly, I don't quite understand. You call player.write() and pass it filedata, but it looks like filedata is just an empty byte array? Shouldn't you need to pass it the inputStream at some point?

Comment: @ChaseRoberts At the time: int lengthOfAudioClip = inputStream.read(filedata, 0, audioLength); was used to fill the buffer, I'm not sure if it still is, I haven't worked with Android in a few years.